# Error while converting xml to json

Tags: xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt-3.0

When I am converting from XML to JSON using XSLT in java the following error occurs:

> Required item type of first argument of fn:xml-to-json() is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <string key="student">john</string>
   <string key="class">Bachelors</string>
   <string key="subjects">
         <subject>
            <subjects>maths</subjects>   
         </subject>
   </string>
</map>
```

**XSLT(Xml to Json) :**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/> 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:param name="xmlText"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 
  <xsl:template name="init">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xml-to-json($xmlText)"/> 
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Error :**

```
Type error at char 12 in xsl:copy-of/@select on line 30 column 50 of json2xml.xsl:
    XPTY0004: Required item type of first argument of fn:xml-to-json() is node(); 
    supplied value has item type xs:string Exception in thread "main" net.sf.saxon.s9api.SaxonApiException: 
    Required item type of first argument of fn:xml-to-json() is node(); 
    supplied value has item type xs:string at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:599) 
    at com.xmltojson.sampleclass.SimpleJaxp.main(SimpleJaxp.java:44)Caused by: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: 
    Required item type of first argument of fn:xml-to-json() is node(); 
    supplied value has item type xs:string
```

Comment: Well, how do you pass in that parameter? Consider to simply pass in XML as the primary input document and use e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:sequence select="xml-to-json(.)"/></xsl:template>`. Or make sure the parameter you pass in is not a string but a node. As an alternative, if you have a string param then you could use `<xsl:sequence select="xml-to-json(parse-xml($xmlText))"/>`.

Comment: Additionally, the XML you have is not a valid instance of the schema for the input to `xml-to-json` I think, so you would need to transform it first to remove the `subject` content or escape it to ensure the content of the `string key="subjects"` is a simple string.

Comment: @MartinHonnen when i am passing string as xml-to-json(parse-xml($xmlText)), it is throwing xml-to-json: element found in wrong namespace: Q{ } Event.

Comment: I don't see any element named `Event` in the snippet you have posted. And I have already pointed out that `xml-to-json` expects a defined format and not arbitrary XML. Start with a simple example from https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-xml-to-json instead of using your own XML if you want to have some input that ought to work.

Comment: Error on line 30 in a stylesheet that does not even have that many lines does not seem possible.

Comment: @MartinHonnen i am able to convert from xml to json and json to xml, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've down-voted the question because you clearly haven't taken enough care over it: the error message refers to an `xsl:copy-of` instruction that isn't in the code you have shown us; and you haven't shown us how the stylesheet is invoked and how the value of `$xmlText` is supplied.

However (consolidating what has already been suggested in the comments), you need to:

(a) ensure that the argument to xml-to-json() is a node. If you're starting from a URI, call the doc() or document() function to get a node. If you're starting from a string containing lexical XML, call the parse-xml() function.

(b) ensure that the node that you pass is valid against the schema (for the XML representation of JSON) defined in the spec. For example, this schema does not allow `subject` as a child of `string`. (I'm not sure what output you want to achieve here: if you want the JSON output to be in the form

```
"subjects": "<subject><subjects>maths</subjects></subject>"
```

then you should change the input to

```
<string key="subjects"><![CDATA[<subject><subjects>maths</subjects></subject>]]></string>
```

(Further complications arise if there are newlines present, but that would be a separate question).